# Does Datepicker have an ID

Tags: css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using date picker in my website and it works fine but I'm trying to set the font size of the calendar & time slider section. I've found that you can do this in css using the code:

```
<body>
font-size: 60%;
</body>
```

but what if you don't want to set the `<body>`? Is there a specific ID for datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target it like so

```
div.ui-datepicker{
     font-size:10px;
}
```

Set this in a stylesheet loaded after the ui-files

div.ui-datepicker is needed in case ui-widget is mentioned after ui-datepicker in the declaration

Comment: Thank you, that's a huge help. Do you know if there's any way to load the date picker from a div rather than an input field? I'd like it to be selected from an icon and then have the result echoed into an alt field but I'm not sure how this would be possible

Comment: Here is how you do that http://forum.jquery.com/topic/attaching-datepicker-to-an-icon-for-a-hidden-input-field

Comment: Thank you, this is a huge help, although I've found that this script doesn't actually work for the "hidden" input as it suggests but it does work for other inputs

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. If you are referring to jquery-ui, then right click on the calendar you will get a box at the bottom of the screen then corresponding class names and id names and css properties can be found there